# Need a way to edit HTML documents inline

Tags: html, html-editor

The use case: sometimes I need to read long articles in HTML format. For example: the HTML5 spec in a single HTML page. As I progress through the article, I want to be able to selectively delete parts of it. I wish to do this so that when I re-read the article later on to understand it better, I could skip over the parts I don't need to read again.

Ideally I would like to just be able to open the HTML page in a browser and have basic notepad like text editing capabilities (select text, hit delete).
However, I don't mind having to copy the HTML page into another program, as long as that program perfectly preserves the article style (for example, when I copied the HTML5 spec into Microsoft Word, some of the section highlights did not transfer over. That is a problem for me).

I'm using both Windows and Linux. My main browser is Firefox, but I have all the major browsers installed.

Comment: Don't know about such software, but I'd try browsing some FF/Chrome Extensions, there may be one for this purpose. There's Dreamweaver obviously, but it's expensive and a complete overkill.

Comment: You only need to remove parts (not edit them, or add new ones), right? And you would be fine with design changes (depending on what exactly you remove, e.g., when removing a `div` that is needed for the CSS to work as intended)?

Comment: @unor Yes it's enough to just remove parts. Being able to edit would be a bonus but is not necessary. If the removal of a div affects style that is acceptable, however what I really need to be able to remove is text, images, lists, headings, and so on. Basically, remove content, not the HTML metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this without any plugins or additional programs. You only need a browser.

Open the document in your favorite browser, and activate the developer console. Run the following code:

```
document.designMode = "on";
```

Now the whole HTML page is editable.